# Program that blocks all TCP connections

Tags: windows-7, tcp

Is there a program for Windows 7 that blocks all TCP connections, and ask for permission to use a new IP, then remembers?

I cannot find anything like this and firewalls don't block every single IP .

Comment: Outbound or inbound TCP connections? and must it be by IP, or can you trust a single program to connect to any IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the commercial firewalls for PCs has options to do this.  A long time ago when I used zone alarm, it prompted me on every single IP use and asked for verification.

More recently, I have been using the Outpost Security Suite and its firewall.  It is very configurable, to the point when it will do as you wanted and block everything and enable the activity either one time or remember it.

Comment: I really liked the outpost (: and yes, a lot of configurations and full block

Answer (score 2):

Besides 3rd party firewalls, you can also use one of the following to enhance the functionality of the inbuilt **Windows Firewall**:

1) [**Windows Firewall Notifier**](http://wokhan.online.fr/progs.php?sec=WFN)

[image: 1]

- Enables the Windows embedded firewall
- Sets the firewall to block both inbound and outbound connections for which no rule exists
- Enables the default Windows firewall inbound connection notification
- Enables the Windows firewall outbound connections logging (disabled by default)
- Creates a scheduled task linked to the Windows firewall event log entries, allowing Windows Firewall Notifier to be launched when needed only

2) [**Windows Firewall Control**](http://www.binisoft.org/wfc.php):

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

- Just one small executable file. All features are packed in the same file.
- Intuitive and easy accessible interface in the system tray.
- Full support with standard user accounts.
- Possibility to create temporary rules.
- Disable the ability of other programs to add Windows Firewall exceptions.
- Multiple and easier ways of creating new rules in Windows Firewall.
- Full support of creating, modifying and deleting of Window Firewall rules.
- Lock feature which can disable the access to the settings of the program.
- Shell integration into the right click context menu of the executable files.
- Search for invalid rules with the possibility to delete them.
- Search for executable files through folders and create new rules in seconds.
- Choose if you want the program to start at user logon.
- Import and export the settings of the program.
- Protection to unauthorized uninstallation.
- Possibility to restore previous settings at uninstallation.
- Learning Mode which provides notifications for outgoing blocked connections.

Comment: interesting too, I will also give it a try